# Problem involving ideals contained in prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

[image]

So far I have used the hint and have done the following:

Let $i=1,2$. Suppose that $I\subseteq P_1\cup P_2$, but that $I$ is not properly contained in $P_i$ for any $i$. Then there is an $a_i$ such that $a_i \in I\setminus P_i$. Then $a_1+a_2 \in I\setminus (P_1\cup P_2)= \emptyset$. This is not possible, so $I\subseteq P_1$ or $I\subseteq P_2$.

Now I want to extend this result for $i=n$, where $n$ is a positive integer greater than or equal to $2$. I want to try a similar approach where I let $a_j \in I\setminus \left( \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1, i\neq j}^n P_i \right)$ so then $a_j\in P_j$, but I have absolutely no idea what to do from there. Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** One way to do this is to show that if $I\not\supset P_i$ for all $i$, then there are elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in I$ such that for each $i$, $x_i\in P_j$ when $j\ne i$ but $x_i\not\in P_i$. Consider $\sum_i x_i$.